# Apache2 - Configure two websites, one with ip/port, one with domain

Tags: apache-http-server, virtual-host

I am hosting two websites on a Raspberry Pi Apache2 server.
One website has a domain name, while the second site doesn't. I want to access the second one with the server IP on same port but without a domain name.

So to access the first one, I would type `domainname.com` and for the second `1.2.3.4`.

With this current setup, both the domain name AND the IP go to the first website.

Here are my two `.conf` files:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domainname.com
    ServerAlias www.domainname.com

    ServerAdmin domainname@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domainname.com/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerName raspberrypi  

    ServerAdmin domainname@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domainname2.com/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

What should I put in `ServerName` for the second website? Since it doesn't have a domain and I'm just accessing it by IP?

I also tried using `_default_` but it didn't seem to do anything?

Comment: You can't access 2 different web servers on the same port and IP address. Possible [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: @DavidPostill But you can have two websites on same IP and port number. Its the `ServerName` in the HTTP request that allows Apache to distinguish which one the client wants.

Comment: @Anaksunaman Thanks a lot, i do not express myself well in english still. Appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that you need to "reverse" the entries for your websites. Per the current Apache 2.4 documentation on [Name-based Virtual Host Support](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html):

> If no matching `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` is found in the set of virtual hosts containing the most specific matching IP address and port combination, then the first listed virtual host that matches that will be used.

So your configuration files (in order) should be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName raspberrypi  

    ServerAdmin domainname@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domainname2.com/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domainname.com
    ServerAlias www.domainname.com

    ServerAdmin domainname@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domainname.com/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Note that the `_default_` entry should be unnecessary. Any request that doesn't match `raspberrypi` or `domainname.com`/`www.domainname.com` (such as `1.2.3.4`) should be matched to the first virtual host (`raspberrypi`).

Comment: Thank you a lot. How would i change the order if those 2 where in separate files?

Comment: I solved this by renaming the one i wanted to be default to come earlier alphabetically. So `1mainsite.conf` and `2secondsite.conf`